# Use of Would have been

Tags: sentence-construction

I heard below conversation recently which i feel is incorrect.
As per my knowledge "would have been" is used to talk about past possibilities.
But in below conversation would have been i think used talk about future possibility.

> A: Will you go to Shop? 
>  
>   B: No, it been so late now. By the time I reached there shop would have been closed.

I think B should have use would be instead of *would have been.*

Please provide more light on use of *would have been.*

Comment: I'd probably phrase it (with other corrections as well):  Are you going to the store?  No, it's too late now.  By the time I get there it'll [it will] be closed.

Comment: *By the time I reached there shop would have been closed* - is **ungrammatical.**

Comment: The capitalization of Shop makes me think it is meant as a noun - so an article is missing. "It been so late now" is ungrammatical. The second "shop" certainly misses an article. "Reached" is an improper use of a past tense. "Would have been" is an irrealis, and indeed also ungrammatical. But I would not worry about _one_ little detail in this collection of mishaps. Jim's suggestion fixes them all.

Comment: @Jim Perhaps "By the time I got there it {would be/would have/would have been} closed" since the speaker has already said she will not go?

Comment: @StoneyB- Agreed. Probably better. In casual conversation I'd probably find myself using *will be closed*  9 times out of ten (because I use the contraction *It'll* which is easier to say that "it'd")  but in writing I'd probably correct it to "it would be"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the following sentences.

> A: Will you go to Shop?
>   B: No, it been so late now. By the time I reached there shop would have been closed.

Firstly, to address your question of the use of *would have been*:
You are correct in that *would have been* is past-tense, not future-tense.
The correct term to use for future-tense is **will be**.

Now on to the other problems:

*Will you go to Shop?* does not seem correct.

I think it probably should say *Will you go to the shop*?

However, if you replace the generic noun of shop with a brand name like *Target*, then *Will you go to Target*, will be correct.

*No, it been so late now* is incorrect as well. It should be *No, it's too late now.*

*By the time I reached there* is also wrong. Reached is generally used for reaching goals, reaching to grab something from the shelf, etc. Not for getting or going somewhere. So it should be *By the time I get there* or *By the time I arrive there*

So in conclusion, the final conversation should be like this :

> A: Will you go to the shop?
>   B: No, it's too late now. By the time I get there, the shop will be closed.